# Monitor success count for Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We are using Azure Function with Node.js.

In the Azure portal UI, next to the list of each function Invocation Log (in the Monitor tab) we see two counters: "Recent success count" and "Recent errors count", is there any programatic way (or API) to monitor these counters?

[image]

Also, I wasn't able to find a way to configure an alert on a function invocation success or failure.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest, use application Insight, build your own query and pin your result in the dashboard. you can set an alert on same query result.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An option to programmatically access the raw logging data by connecting to the storage account associated with your Function App.

Once connected to that account, you'll see storage tables named "AzureWebJobsHostLogYYYMM" containing all the log data.

About alerts, currently, that feature is not available out of the box with Azure Functions and would require a custom solution like something on top of Application Insights. You can see an example [here](https://github.com/christopheranderson/azure-functions-app-insights-sample).

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use apis that are unsupported, you can get this data from:
`<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/definitions?host=<sitename>&limit=11`

That's the call that the Monitor tab makes to retrieve the data:
https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/blob/1bfec15511a55df1599fcb839b989b8760985d4f/AzureFunctions.Client/app/services/function-monitor.service.ts#L41

Currently there isn't a way to alert on invocation success or failure, the best way to do this would be via the function code itself (before exiting the function log the status in some way). Functions is working to add Application Insights integration which should improve the available monitoring data, and may add before/after invocation hooks as well.

Feel free to add any feature requests at https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues

Answer (score 1):

To monitor success count of Azure Function one of the following can be selected

1. From Invocation Logs
2. Metrics api

2 ways to get the Invocation Logs:

method 1: Invocation logs of an Azure Function can be retrieved from the storage account associated with the Azure Function app. Invocation logs of every month will be available in a separate table storage. Challenge i faced was applying filter on the records were not possible, response was slow in case of huge number of logs. This link could be of help,
https://gist.github.com/syron/c190638dd77b54adcfb4b9406ed88652

method 2: As Matt Mason mentioned,

```
<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/definitions?host=<sitename>&limit=<count>.
```

Limiting the number of records is possible here. Comparatively better responsive. Settled down with this solution to monitor the Azure Function in my custom application and works as expected

Metrics API:
There is an exposed rest API available to get metrics of Azure Function Apps.

API:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/microsoft.web/sites//providers/microsoft.insights/metricdefinitions?api-version=2018-01-01

Out of the whole list of Azure Function metrics "FunctionExecutionCount" and "Http5xx"  can be used to compute success count for azure functions.
Difference in value of the metrics, "FunctionExecutionCount" and "Http5xx"  will get success count of an azure function.

Refer to the following link for exposed REST API to get Azure Function metrics:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metricdefinitions/list

Refer to the following link for more details on the metrics:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-supported-metrics